# Getting content from custom tags and removing custom tags not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the content between `<amazon></amazon>` tags.

```
<amazon><a rel="nofollow"><img border="0" ></a><img width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
</amazon>
```

I've tried regex to get the html inbetween tags.

```
 preg_match_all('/<amazon>(.*?)<\/amazon>/s', $string, $matches);
 $amazon = $matches[1];
```

but this isn't working.  It's just blank when i check the database.

Also i want to remove `<amazon></amazon>` and all content between.  I tried regex and also not working.

```
 $string = preg_replace('~\<amazon\>(.+?)\</amazon\>~','',$string);
```

How do i solve?

Comment: In the given example of custom tag, there's nothing except HTML code in between `<amazon>` and `</amazon>`. The code seems to fetch the contents between the HTML tags when something actually exists. Are you sure there is still an issue?